# Integration of JAX-WS to Spring Boot

Tags: java, web-services, spring-boot

I have an existing API which has both JAX-RS and JAX-WS. I want to migrate it into a Spring Boot application. What I've done for JAX-RS part is registering that class:

```
@GET
@Path("/ping")
@Produces("text/plain")
String ping();
```

into a `Jersey Config` which extends `ResourceConfig`. Here is the example from JAX-WS of same class:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "Ping", action = "ping-app")
String ping();
```

Since I've used reference implementations of JAX-RS and JAX-WS I hope that it should be easy to migrate it into Spring Boot. I've easily done JAX-RS integration. Is there any such simple way to integrate JAX-WS too?

Comment: Any particular reason why Jersey and not use Spring MVC supported `RestController`?

Answer (score 3):

Ideally you'd want to use a Spring Boot Starter to assist you. According to [their documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-starter):

> Starters are a set of convenient dependency descriptors that you can
>   include in your application. You get a one-stop-shop for all the
>   Spring and related technology that you need, without having to hunt
>   through sample code and copy paste loads of dependency descriptors.
>   For example, if you want to get started using Spring and JPA for
>   database access, just include the spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
>   dependency in your project, and you are good to go.

Using [this list](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-starters) of official and community starters, it looks like you have the following options:

- `spring-boot-starter-jersey` should be able to handle JAX-RS
- `spring-boot-web-services` might be able to handle JAX-WS. From what I understand, you might need to do things the 'Spring Web Services' way which is different to JAX-WS. It's been a while since I worked with Spring Web Services, so I might be incorrect on this point.
- The Apache CXF starter can support both JAX-RS and JAX-WS which seems to meet your requirement. They have [this guide](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/springboot.html) for their spring boot integration for you to look at.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't use this personally but it seems that spring provides starter pack for JAX-WS

Take a look at [this artifact](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jersey/1.4.1.RELEASE). It should be enough just to add this dependency to your project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by using this dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.6</version>
</dependency>
```

and add this bean in the configuration bean

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;
import org.apache.cxf.Bus;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl;

@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig{

    @Autowired
    private Bus bus;

    @Bean
    public Endpoint endpoint() {
        EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(bus, new SpPortImpl());
        endpoint.publish("/NpcdbService");
        return endpoint;
    }
}
```

SpPortImpl is the class annotated with @WebService